# exec: "dir": executable file not found in %PATH%

Tags: go, exec

```
cmd := exec.Command("cd", "..")
err := cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
}
```

i use os/exec by document,but all command cannot be used.
Error:exec: [commandname]: executable file not found in %PATH%

win11,golang 1.16.5

Answer (score 2):

The `cd` command is builtin to the shell.  It is not a standalone executable that can be exec’ed.

Use [os.Chdir](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Chdir) to change the current working directory of the current process.

Comment: the ’cd‘ just a example.the all command connt be used.for example，“copy”，“dir”...all err:executable file not found in %PATH%

Comment: @cmys1109  `cd` is not an example of the other commands.  The `cd` command does not have an executable on the path as noted by the error message.  The other commands have exeutable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70912210/15021538  look this  cd.   It's not good to use CD as an example

Comment: @cmys1109 I am confused about why your link answers the question.  Maybe somebody else can make sense of this.